# What actually StatePreparation perform in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, state-preparation

I used this method to initialize classical data in a circuit. I would like to know what's under the hood and the complexity of this procedure, but I can't find anything on the internet which suits my thoughts.

The procedure is this: https://qiskit.org/documentation/locale/bn_BN/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.StatePreparation.html

I tried to read the reference, but I'm from a computer science degree and it is over my competences :(, if there is someone which could explain it in simpler terms, I am open to chat.

Thanks to all

Comment: Hi everyone! I solved this by using trappole function on qiskit routine. It shows the circuit in native gates. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into MottonenStatePreparation circuit in pennylane library. It also uses amplitude encoding to encode classical information onto quantum circuits.